# Covariant derivative and $\nabla X$

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, vectors, tensors

If I consider the covariant derivative of a vector field $Y$ with respect to $X$ this is usually indicated as $\nabla_X Y$, but what's about $\nabla X$? This is the covariant derivative of $X$ and I have read it is  tensor field of type (1,1) such that if $Y\in \chi(\cal{M})$ (vector field) and $w\in \chi^*(\cal{M})$ (covector)
$$\nabla X(Y,w)=w(\nabla_XY)$$
Why it is true? I only know that given a smooth function $f$ then $\nabla_{f X} Y=f\nabla_X Y$, but really I can't understand the relationship between $\nabla X$ and $\nabla_X Y$ and so why the expression above holds.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it should be
\begin{equation}
\nabla X(Y,\omega)=\omega(\nabla_YX)
\end{equation}
Over a general [vector bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle) $E\rightarrow M$ we have that the [connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(vector_bundle)) is a map
$$
\Gamma(E)\xrightarrow{\nabla}\Gamma(T^*M\otimes E)
$$
where $\Gamma(-)$ denotes smooth sections. In your case $E=TM$:
$$
\Gamma(TM)\xrightarrow{\nabla}\Gamma(T^*M\otimes TM)
$$
i.e. $\nabla$ eats a vector field and spits out a (1,1) tensor field. We'll work in coordinates for these calculations. So if $\omega$ is a covector field and $Y$ a vector field, then
\begin{align}
\nabla X(Y,\omega)&=\nabla(X^i\partial_i)(Y,\omega) \\
&=(\nabla X^i\otimes\partial_i)(Y,\omega)+(X^i\nabla\partial_i)(Y,\omega) \\
\end{align}
This is since $\nabla$ satisfies a sort of Leibnitz rule. Continuing:
\begin{align}
&=(d(X^i)\otimes\partial_i)(Y,\omega)+(X^i\nabla\partial_i)(Y,\omega)
\end{align}
Since by definition, $\nabla(f)=df$ for any smooth function. Then:
\begin{align}
&=(\partial_m X^idx^m\otimes\partial_i)(Y,\omega)+(X^i\Gamma^{l}_{mi}dx^m\otimes\partial_l)(Y,\omega) \\
\end{align}
Where the $\Gamma$'s are the usual connection coefficients: $\nabla\partial_i=\Gamma^l_{mi}dx^m\otimes\partial_l$. Hence:
\begin{align}
&=(\partial_mX^i)Y^p\omega_\alpha dx^m(\partial_p)\partial_i(dx^\alpha)+X^i\Gamma^l_{mi}Y^p\omega_\alpha dx^m(\partial_p)\partial_l(dx^\alpha) \\
&=(\partial_m X^i)Y^m\omega_i+X^i\Gamma^l_{mi}Y^m\omega_l
\end{align}
On the other hand,
\begin{align}
\omega(\nabla_YX)&=\omega(\nabla_{Y^m\partial_m}X^i\partial_i) \\
&=\omega[Y^m((\partial_m X^i)\partial_i+X^i \nabla_{\partial_m}\partial_i)] \\
&=\omega[Y^m((\partial_m X^i)\partial_i+X^i\Gamma^s_{mi}\partial_s)] \\
&=\omega_ldx^l[Y^m((\partial_m X^s)+X^i\Gamma^s_{mi})\partial_s] \\
&=\omega_l[(\partial_mX^s)Y^m+X^i\Gamma^s_{mi}Y^m]dx^l(\partial_s) \\
&=(\partial_mX^s)Y^m\omega_s+X^i\Gamma^s_{mi}Y^m\omega_s
\end{align}
where I leave the justifications to you. And then replacing dummy indices yields the result.

Comment: Ok thanks! But as I have questioned as comment in the other asnwer: the first expression that you have written is the definition of this tensor $\nabla X$?

Comment: @wimy Not necessarily. It is a map that follows certain axioms as I said, direct calculation shows this happens to be true. You should take a look at the wiki and see its axioms. From there you should then be able to justify the last set of calculations I did and have a better understanding of what a connection is.

Comment: Sorry for my maybe stupid doubts but I can't understand...surely it is my fault..I hope you can help me!

Comment: Ok I have read the wiki but there are things again not clear for me: 1) $\nabla $ is a tensor field of type (1,1) that so has to be applied to a couple of arguments as $\nabla (Y,w)$ (vector and covector), so what is $\nabla X (Y,w)$? 2) The leibniz rule that has to be satisfied, i.e ${\displaystyle \nabla (fs)=df\otimes s+f\nabla s}$, seems to regard the multiplication of s by a function but in the case that you have cited at first we have $ \nabla(X^i\partial_i)(Y,\omega)$ for which I would write $X^i\nabla(\partial_i)(Y,\omega)$ as suggested by  the property "$\nabla_{fX}(s)=f\nabla_X(s)$"

Comment: @wimy These aren't stupid! You'll get it mate, just takes some practice. 1) We have that $\nabla$ is a map from smooth sections to smooth sections. So $\nabla X$ (where $X$ is a vector field) IS the (1,1) tensor field. So $\nabla X$ can be applied to a pair $(Y,\omega)$. 2) Also, recall that, in coordinates, $X=X^i\partial_i$ where $X^i$ are smooth real-valued functions. So the Leibniz rules applies to $X^i$ in the following way: $\nabla (X^i\partial_i)=d(X^i)\otimes\partial_i+X^i\nabla\partial_i$.

Comment: Ok now everything is clear! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This is really not the right way to look at it. $\nabla X$ is a vector-field valued $1$-form $\omega$ whose value  on $Y$ is $\omega(Y)=\nabla_Y X$. That is, it's giving you a (tensorial) map from vector fields to vector fields. It's a section of $T^*M\otimes TM$, and as such is a $(1,1)$-tensor.

Comment: What you have written is by definition of $\nabla X$ or it is a consequence with some reasons?

Comment: It is, in fact, the definition, as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @ Ted Shifrin Ok thanks! Now it is all more reasonable, otherwise I had not able to understand why wa a tensor of type (1,1) and why that expression with $\omega$!